# error when creating a keystore => Exception in thread "main" java.io.EOFException at java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(Unknown Source)

Tags: java, security, keystore, jks

the source code that I followed to create a keystore,

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.security.KeyStore;
import java.security.cert.Certificate;

public class MainClass {

public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
String pass = "wshr.ut";
String alias = "mytest";
String name = "mykeystore";

FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(name);
KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
ks.load(in, pass.toCharArray());

Certificate c = ks.getCertificate(alias);
in.close();
System.out.println(c);

}
}
```

error when running:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.EOFException
at java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore.engineLoad(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore$JKS.engineLoad(Unknown Source)
at java.security.KeyStore.load(Unknown Source)
at MainClass.main(MainClass.java:17)
```

can you plz give me any ideas or solutions to reslove this problem ?

Comment: Well it sounds like your key store file is too short...

Comment: hi jon thanks for your response, what do you mean by "my keystore file is too short ??"

Comment: Exactly what I say. You're opening a file as your keystore. It appears not to be a valid, complete keystore file. I'm not sure what else I can say...

Comment: ok i understand what you say, do you have any idea how to resolve it ??

Answer (score 0):

I just want to post my answer for the future,
I faced the same issue and found the solution ,
that path you pass for the fileInputStream must be the path of keyStore inside java in my case I was on ubuntu 20.04 and java 11 the path was the following: "/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/lib/security/cacerts"
in case you are on windows the path will be: "C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_101/lib/security/cacerts"

make sure also that the password will usually be the default and it is like the following word: "changeit"